# on_reaction_add custom emoji

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I have a command that adds two emojis in my text:

```
await Bot.add_reaction(msg, ":name:id")
await Bot.add_reaction(msg, "✔️")
```

using **on_reaction_add**, when the emoji is clicked, it does something:

```
@Bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    try:
        if reaction.emoji == "<:name:id>":
          ##stuffs

        if reaction.emoji == "✔️":
          ##stuffs

    except KeyError:
        pass
```

however only the ✔️ emoji reacts, when the custom emoji **:name:id** is reacted, it does nothing, what should I do to make it work?
I already tried to use **if reaction.emoji == ":name:id":** without **< >** but also not working..
just to make it clear about **:name:id**, **name** is the name of emoji, and **id** is the id of emoji

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the reaction is with a custom emoji, then `reaction.Emoji` will be a [`discord.Emoji`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Emoji) object that represents that emoji.  Otherwise it will be a string.

```
from discord import Emoji

@Bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    emoji = reaction.emoji
    if isinstance(emoji, Emoji):
        if emoji.name == 'myemoji':
            ...
    else:
        if emoji == '✔️':
            ...
```